# MAMP PRO site very slow when using custom names

Tags: localhost, hosts, mamp-pro

I have had MAMP PRO for a few years and it has always worked fast. Suddenly, however, the pages load extremely slowly, but only when using custom host names.

Loading `10.0.1.43` (my local ip) took 0.026 seconds, while using a custom domain name took 5.556 seconds (213 times as slow).

In `/etc/hosts` the domains are the defined like this:

```
10.0.1.43   testdomain.com  # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
```

Changing `10.0.1.43` to `127.0.0.1` does not make it faster.

My hosts file has about 2000 entries, but it has worked previously with as many entries, and removing them didn't change anything.